# Unable to launch a wpf application on windows XP machine

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-xp, .net-4.5

I have created a `WPF` application with target Framework 4.5 on Windows 8 machine. The application has reference to two c# dlls with same same target framework. I have used Linq to entities to connect to a MS Sql server database in my application.

Now, When I tried to run the same application by running the `exe` file located in Debug folder in a Windows XP machine, it gives following error message

> D:\Main\TPMS\Debug\TPMS.exe is not a valid win32 application.

What is the issue here?

Comment: In the project properties, is the project targeting "x64" rather than "Any CPU"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework 4.5 and later versions are not supported on Windows XP

[NET Framework 4.5 and Windows XP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[.NET Framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) is not supported on windows XP. Try targeting .NET Framework 4.0. Another option is to use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) but since it [lacks support of WPF](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) then you should stick to .NET Framework 4.0